# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a temporary table in MySQL version 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log.  I am getting an error:

```
joe@bigdb [staging]> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
    ->   field_one int
    -> );
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error -1 from storage engine
```

I've checked around, most answers have to do with disabling innodb_force_recovery, so I looked into that:

```
joe@bigdb [staging]> show variables like 'i%recovery%';
    +-----------------------+-------+
    | Variable_name         | Value |
    +-----------------------+-------+
    | innodb_force_recovery | 0     |
    +-----------------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Seems ok there.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: 'Got error -1 from storage engine' seems to indicate some generic error creating or writing to a disk file.  Check that there is sufficient space in the database directory, that the file system permissions are as they should be, and that the mount hasn't become read-only.